# How can you make users stay on the page with no actions with Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to load test a URL with 3000 threads (users) to stay on the URL for a time (for example 30 minutes) and wait there until all the threads are loaded.

It is possible to achieve this with JMeter? I saw that after I get the 200 OK HTTP Response the connection is closing.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that JMeter sends [`Connection` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Connection) with the value of `keep-alive`

It can be done by ticking `Use KeepAlive` box in the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler:

[image]

In that case the connection will close ([TCP FIN](https://ipwithease.com/what-is-tcp-fin-packet/) packet will be sent) when your thread stops so if you want to keep the connections open for 30 minutes - use either [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler or a relevant [JMeter Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-timer) to wait for the desired amount of time.